# How do i change this so when i run the functions it adds to my .txt file?

Tags: python, function, file-handling

Im supposed to make a function for adding name and number to a.txt file, and one for reading the file. What am I doing wrong and how do I correct it? first post so I dont know if something is in the wrong format, sorry.

```
def add():
    while True:
        name = input("Name and number: ")
        with open("Telefon.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(name)
        f.close()
        if name == "Enter":
            break
        
def read():        
    f = open("Telefon.txt", "r")
    print(f.read)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain logical and optimizations mistake in your code you should not open file again and again and close it in loop, also use empty condition to terminate the loop e.g. press enter without entering any thing. For reading, I replaced your read method with redlines method

```
def add():
    with open("Telefon.txt", "a") as f:
        while True:
            name = input("Name and number: ")
            f.write(name + '\n')
            if name == "":
                break
        
def read():        
    f = open("Telefon.txt", "r")
    print("".join(f.readlines()))

add()
read()
```

The output is following

[image]